# How do I verify that my partitions are being used

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu by manually specifying the partitions /, /swap & /home. I am new to Ubuntu so I would like to verify whether these partitions are working properly.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/debsums.1.html (?) Thing is... this is done by Ubuntu itself during installation (the deb packages are checked against their md5 checksum).

Comment: what is that? I could not understand a thing... sorry

Comment: Hi @Cool_Coder , That command will check every installed package in your system . so that you can know is properly installed or something break behind the wall. very useful command.

Comment: @Cool_Coder glance at examples section of that man page. It will guide on usage .

Comment: Hi Jai what should do if I only want to check whether the partitions are created correctly & are working as per spec?

Comment: No idea what "windows experience index" is, but you should ask it in a separate question since there should only be one question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `df` command shows how much free/used space is on each mounted filesystem, and the `mount` command shows what filesystems are mounted.  You can use either to make sure /home is mounted.  `free` shows how much used/free ram/swap you have, so you can use that to verify that your swap partition is mounted, or `cat /proc/swaps` for a simple list of mounted swap partitions.

Answer (score 0):

A gui based tool is also an option.

GParted provides a graphical view of devices and partitions. It might already be installed on your system:

```
Applications | System Tools | Administration | GParted
```

If you're using Unity - type GParted in Dash should find it

If it's not installed you may install it using Software Center